# Criar novas linhas e colunas para valores não existentes

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho um data frame em que a coluna "anos" não está preenchida todos os dados que preciso. Eu precisaria, para cada observação, a escala de 1988 à 2014, preenchendo com 0 (zero) os anos cujos valores não aparecerem no banco original.

O data frame é o seguinte:

```
structure(list(A1 = c(110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 
110002, 110002, 110002, 110002, 110002, 110002, 110002, 110002, 
110002, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003), anos = c(1999, 2003, 
2006, 2008, 2012, 1996, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2013, 1991, 2006, 2007, 2010), n = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), cs2 = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L), groups = structure(list(A1 = c(110001, 
110002, 110003), .rows = list(1:5, 6:14, 15:18)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Note que para a primeira observação parecem apenas os anos de 1999, 2003, 2006, 2008 e 2012. Eu precisaria de todos os anos de 1988 à 2014, preenchendo com 0 nas colunas "n" e "cs2" os casos em que não há valor no banco original. Ficaria mais ou menos assim (fiz 'não mão' para ilustrar):

```
structure(list(A1 = c(110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 
110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 
110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 
110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001), anos = c(1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013), `n ` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), cs2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(A1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), anos = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `n ` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), cs2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Tentei usar o `mutate` mais a combinação `if_else`, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira coisa que eu faria é avisar para o `R` quais são os valores que `anos` pode assumir. No caso, estes valores vão de 1988 a 2014. Para mim, a melhor maneira de fazer isto é convertendo a coluna `anos` em fator e, explicitamente, dizendo que valores ela pode assumir:

```
dados$anos <- factor(dados$anos, levels = seq(1988, 2014))
```

Isto feito, basta usar a função `complete` do `dplyr` para encontrar todas as combinações possíveis entre `anos` e `A1`:

```
dados %>%
  complete(anos, nesting(A1), fill = list(n = 0, cs2 = 0))
# A tibble: 81 x 4
# Groups:   A1 [3]
   anos      A1     n   cs2
   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1988  110001     0     0
 2 1989  110001     0     0
 3 1990  110001     0     0
 4 1991  110001     0     0
 5 1992  110001     0     0
 6 1993  110001     0     0
 7 1994  110001     0     0
 8 1995  110001     0     0
 9 1996  110001     0     0
10 1997  110001     0     0
11 1998  110001     0     0
12 1999  110001     1     1
13 2000  110001     0     0
14 2001  110001     0     0
15 2002  110001     0     0
16 2003  110001     2     3
17 2004  110001     0     0
18 2005  110001     0     0
19 2006  110001     2     5
20 2007  110001     0     0
# … with 61 more rows
```

Perceba que bastou informar qual valor eu gostaria que `n` e `cs2` assumissem para que o `R` automaticamente o colocasse em seu lugar.

Para obter novamente `anos` como uma variável numérica, rode

```
dados$anos <- as.numeric(levels(dados$anos))
```

Comment: Pode também ser `mutate(anos = factor(anos, levels = 1988:2014)) %>%` antes do `complete(...)`. Fica tudo seguido.

Comment: De fato, assim fica mais organizado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus e Rui, funcionou perfeitamente!